# Typesetting horizontal line used in logic

Tags: math-mode, logic

I am trying to typeset a set of rules of a calculs which should look as the examples in the attached pictured.

[image]

In the example rules are written in classical notation of logic.

I especially wonder about the horizontal line that splits the requirements from the conclusion. What's the best way to typeset this line such that it expands automatically?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's quite easy with `bussproofs`; the hardest part is getting the alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{bussproofs}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tabular}{@{} l >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.7\textwidth} @{}}
\textsc{Scope} &
  \begin{prooftree}
  \AxiomC{$A \xrightarrow{\alpha} A'$}
  \AxiomC{$u$ does not occur in $\alpha$}
  \BinaryInfC{$\nu u.A \xrightarrow{\alpha} \nu u.A'$}
  \end{prooftree}
\\
\textsc{Par} &
  \begin{prooftree}
  \AxiomC{$A \xrightarrow{\alpha} A'$}
  \AxiomC{$\mathit{bv}(\alpha)\cap\mathit{fv}(B)=\mathit{bn}(\alpha)\cap\mathit{fn}(B)=\emptyset$}
  \BinaryInfC{$A\mid B \xrightarrow{\alpha} A'\mid B$}
  \end{prooftree}
\end{tabular}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different solution, which also provides a `boxedprooftree` environment that can be used anywhere. It has an optional argument for vertical alignment, just like `tabular` or `\parbox`: it can be `t` or `b` for top or bottom alignment (default `c` for vertical centering).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bussproofs}

\newenvironment{boxedprooftree}[1][c]
 {\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}}
 {\DisplayProof\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tabular}{@{} l c @{}}
\textsc{Scope} &
  \begin{boxedprooftree}
  \AxiomC{$A \xrightarrow{\alpha} A'$}
  \AxiomC{$u$ does not occur in $\alpha$}
  \BinaryInfC{$\nu u.A \xrightarrow{\alpha} \nu u.A'$}
  \end{boxedprooftree}
\\[3ex]
\textsc{Par} &
  \begin{boxedprooftree}
  \AxiomC{$A \xrightarrow{\alpha} A'$}
  \AxiomC{$\mathit{bv}(\alpha)\cap\mathit{fv}(B)=\mathit{bn}(\alpha)\cap\mathit{fn}(B)=\emptyset$}
  \BinaryInfC{$A\mid B \xrightarrow{\alpha} A'\mid B$}
  \end{boxedprooftree}
\end{tabular}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this great answer. If you got any time to spare, I'd be happy for a little explanation of the column description of the tabular environement, i.e. `@{} l >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.7\textwidth} @{}`

Comment: The `prooftree` environment doesn't like to be set in a horizontal box (I believe there is a variant for this); so I resorted to put them in a minipage, which is what the `m` option does, with vertical centering. I'll look for an easier method.

Comment: I just noticed when adding additional rules to the tabular the a part of them does not seem to be centered correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a fraction:

```
\frac{A \overset{\alpha}{\to} A' \text{\hspace{1cm}\textit{u} does not occur in }\alpha}{\nu u.A \overset{\alpha}{\to} \nu u.A'}
```

resulting in

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is an adaption of [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286824/) using `ebproof` which was inspired by `bussproofs` and has a fairly similar syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ebproof}

\begin{document}

  \begin{prooftree*}
    \Hypo{A \xrightarrow{\alpha} A'}
    \Hypo{u \text{ does not occur in } \alpha}
    \Infer[left label={\textsc{Scope}}]2{\nu u.A \xrightarrow{\alpha} \nu u.A'}
  \end{prooftree*}
  \begin{prooftree*}
    \Hypo{A \xrightarrow{\alpha} A'}
    \Hypo{\mathit{bv}(\alpha)\cap\mathit{fv}(B)=\mathit{bn}(\alpha)\cap\mathit{fn}(B)=\emptyset}
    \Infer[left label={\textsc{Par}}]2{A\mid B \xrightarrow{\alpha} A'\mid B}
  \end{prooftree*}

\end{document}
```

The starred version of the environment is equivalent to wrapping the non-starred version in the `center` environment. The environment may be used in text or maths mode.

[image: ebproof demo]